# can't ssh to ec2 in vpn

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, vpn

I have two ec2s residing in the same vpc having the same subnet and the same security group. the vpc has vpn setup with my ip. I can log fine to one of the instances using its private ip but I can not log to the other instance. everything in the two instances looks identical (vpc, subnet and SG wise). what am I missing?

I also created the same question in stackoverflow I know I shouldn't be doing that but after posting the question there I thought that this site is more appropriate for this kind of questions.

Comment: Have you tried to login from working ec2 to problematic one? And what do you mean by - can't login? Did you get some specific error?

Comment: You talk about private ip for logging. Are you logging into those two servers from another ec2 on the same vpc? Most of the time something is missing on security groups, double/tiple check them

Answer (score 1):

This has bitten me many times over the years.  Make sure that the IP of your VPN is added to your security group for SSH.  Many times I thought for sure I had it there only to discover it was indeed missing.